# GridView repeating one image

Tags: java, android

This question has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer so sorry if it is a duplicate question. but my gridView is just repeating the last image i pass to it.

here is my onActivityResult where i select up to six images from the phones gallery

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE)
        {
            ArrayList<Bitmap> items = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            String[] imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");

            try
            {
                lnrImages.removeAllViews();
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i=0; i<imagesPath.length; i++)
            {
                yourbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPath[i]);
                items.add(yourbitmap);
            }

            adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.id.grdImages, items);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my imageadapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>
{
Bitmap bm;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> items;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Bitmap> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        bm = items.get(i);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        return imageView;
    }

    return imageView;

}
}
```

thanks for any feed back it is much appreciated as a programmer in training.

Comment: Anyone think of anything?

Comment: What is the use of last loop? Why do you invoke `imageView.setImageBitmap` several times.

Comment: yea mike_d_boss just pointed that out to me, i thougth i had to loop through all images passes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this block...

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) { 
     bm = items.get(i);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bm); 
     return imageView;
     }
```

And Add this

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(items.get(position));
```

Comment: whats the difference between that and what i have?

Comment: Its bad practice to use bitmaps .. You should rather try Glide or Picasso and pass only string for image paths

Comment: ok something i will look into i suppose, but im almost certain my problem is within the getView method in the imageadapter

Comment: Glad to help. But don't use bitmap as I said and try Glide/Picasso. And also mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoked the getView method ,you don't use for loop~'

Remember ListView and GridView needs a data sources , no matter when you wanna change stuff on the listView /gridView ,you change the data sources.

in the getView method you just do this

```
  @Override
```

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

```
ImageView imageView;

if (convertView == null) {
  .....
}
else{
  .....
  imageView.setImageBitMap(items.get(position));
  //items is the data sources and position is the method gave you .
}

!!! no for loop

return imageView;
```